# Definition question: Is the expanding history of a stochastic process also a stochastic process but on another probability space?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, definition

So usually we take $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and $X_t \in \mathbb{R} \; (\text{event space}) \quad \forall \; t \in \mathbb{R} \;(\text{time})$.

If we consider the process of paths of $X$ up to time $t$, $Y_t \equiv \{X_s: s \leq t\}$, is this still considered a stochastic process on some other extended probability space? Or is this not possible for some technical reason?

Comment: Yes. So the question is how to define the filration of sigma-algebras for $Y_t$? I feel like I have seen this in the past in classic texts like Feller but haven't found it again. I see folks in the stochastic delay equations doing things in this space using "linear chain trick" but there are probably other approaches?

Comment: Ah, OK. I think my problem is that I don't quite understand how $Y_t$ works. Your notation is a little confusing to me. In particular, you're overloading $S$ and $s$. What is $Y_t$?

Comment: Yeah it's a bit confusing ... I'll change $S$ to something else. So $Y_t$ is the history of $X$ up to time $t$. So it's a path up to time $t$. $s$ is just some other time index. The key problem is that the length (dimension) of the path $Y_t$ grows as $t$ increases.

Comment: One thing I don't understand about your question, perhaps you could clarify: I don't see why you'd need a new domain; only a new range. $Y_t$ should already be adapted to $\Omega, \mathcal{F}_t$. The filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ is already ordered by inclusion, so $\mathcal{F}_{t_1} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{t_2}$ when $t_1 \leq t_2$. So $\mathcal{F}_t$ already knows the whole path of $X_t$.

Comment: Yes "range" or "event space" should be the only completely new construct. The other bits  I guess are just products of the rest ($\Omega$ and $P$).